# passing data from javascript to servlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have values of checkbox and as soon as I click delete the values and the type must be sent to a servlet called DeleteServlet. Please help me how to send the values?

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function get_check_value(chkbox){
           if(chkbox.checked){
          var Values=chkbox.value;
          //send this Values to servlet

             }

    }
    function doDelete(theClick){
    var type=theClick;
//send this type to servlet
    alert(type);

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <%String user=request.getParameter("Users"); %>
    <body>
    <%

    String User[]=user.trim().split(" ");

    for(int i=0;i<User.length;i++){%>
     <center>
        <form name='list' action='AddUserServlet'>

     <%  out.println("<input type='checkbox' name='user" + i + "' value='"+ User[i] + "' onClick='return get_check_value(this)'>" + User[i]+ "</input>" ); %>  

    </form> 

    <%}%>

        <input type="submit" value="ADD" name="b1" >
        <input type="submit" value="MODIFY" name="b1">
     <input type="submit" value="DELETE" name="b1" onClick="return doDelete(value)" > 

      </center>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried this  "document.list.user.value" in an alert box it comes as undefined object. To send to a servlet I tried the following line but nothing is read

```
chk_val=chkbox.value;
document.add.action = "AddUserServlet?type=delete&name="+chk_val;
 document.add.submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Javascript for this at all.

Just change your code so that the HTML form is generated as follows:

```
<form action="AddUserServlet" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="user" value="5">

    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="ADD">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="MODIFY">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="DELETE">
</form>
```

(the checkbox value must be the unique user ID)

Then use `request.getParameterValues()` in your `AddUserServlet`:

```
String b1 = request.getParameter("b1");
if ("DELETE".equals(b1)) {
    String[] users = request.getParameterValues("user");
    // ...
}
```

The `users` array will contain the checked values (1, 2, 3, 4 and/or 5).

Comment: Ya I can do like this but the problem is I get the values from database. I must use for loop here to get values. Will I be able to change the code so?

Comment: Certainly. Just replace `name='user" + i + "'` by `name='user'`. Use your logical thinking powers :)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use jQuery javascript libary. It is easy to use and you will find lots of tutorials.
Here is good tutorial about get method(AJAX) http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Is it possible to do it without javascript?